# access resource files in outer jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, fat

I'm writing some microservices (fat jar) which expose some http endpoint using a router. As I like every microservice automatically expose a /doc endpoint which just fetches a /src/main/resource/doc/readme.adoc and renders that to html I created a new project doc-renderer.

It puts a /doc endpoint to the router and in its handler method it tries to access the readme.adoc and renders it to html. If I now use that bundle as dependency within my microservices and put a readme.adoc under /src/main/resources/doc/ it isn't really working as it loads the readme.adoc in the dependend bundle.

So this is the resulting jar structure

microservice.jar
- /doc/
    - readme.adoc
- /lib/
    - docRenderer.jar    ( here it tries to load the readme from outside )
    - /doc/
        - readme.adoc

To load the resource I use: getClass().getResourceAsStream("/doc/readme.adoc")

Is there a way I can force it to always use the /doc/readme.adoc file from the outer jar?

Regards, Marco